# cakephp css and images problem at localhost

Tags: cakephp

I've downloaded a project from a root server. It acts there very fine. But when i run the project in the localhost on xampp environment, didn't find the any css nor any images. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also verify the contents of your .htaccess files in the root install directory, in `/app` and `/app/webroot`. Depending if you are serving CakePHP from a subdirectory (like http://domain.com/somesubdirectory/) you might have to add a `RewriteBase` directive to your .htaccess file in `/app/webroot/`. Details [here](http://cookingwithcakephp.blogspot.com/2008/04/installing-cakephp-into-subdirectory.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions of the /app/webroot/css and /app/webroot/img folders. Also check if you have mod_rewrite properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial which talks about mod_rewrite:

[link text](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1533/A-Note-on-mod_rewrite)

"Occasionally a new user will run in to mod_rewrite issues, so I'll mention them marginally here. If the CakePHP welcome page looks a little funny (no images or css styles), it probably means mod_rewrite isn't functioning on your system. Here are some tips to help get you up and running: ..."