# Running a CakePHP project on Localhost

Tags: cakephp, installation

I have downloaded a CakePHP project from an online server and need to make it work locally, to do some changes.
I'm facing a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341422/cakephp-css-and-images-problem-at-localhost) and have tried all possible solutions, with no luck.

Here's the situations:

- Site home is in localhost/xpto (c:\xampp\htdocs\xpto) -> here, the site appears unformatted (no CSS) and too slow.
- If I access localhost/xpto/something, I get the site with the CSS, but some links wont work.

I have mod_rewrite loaded (phpinfo()) together with the 3 .htaccess files, but still experience this problem.

Is there any known issue that I can explore to fix my site?
Please redirect me to any guides or tutorials that you may feel relevant to my issue

Comment: CakePHP is "just" a a bunch of PHP scripts, it should work out-of-the-box. I'd recommend to give XAMPP a try, it works for me ever since I've installed it the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RewriteBase directive in .htaccess.

e.g my dev space is on my localhost, is located in /home/ati/public_html/cakerbs, under a subdir in my userdir. The rewriteBase looks like as follows in the root of the cake:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /~ati/cakerbs
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

in the app directory .htacces:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /~ati/cakerbs
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

in the webroot directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~ati/cakerbs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your XAMPP apache settings, it's very likely your current config is blocking things like the .htaccess files (I know EasyPHP does this by default with Cake). What I do to get around this error is to add a VirtualHost to my config like such:

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/xpto/"
ServerName xpto.dev
ServerAlias www.xpto.dev
ErrorLog "logs/xpto-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/xtpo-access.log" common
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It may be better to update your whole config properly, but seeing as it's a dev environment for me, this does just fine. (Don't forget to add any hosts to your windows hosts file)

Then just open your favourite browser and go to http://xpto.dev/ and it should load up.

This may help your more: http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/

Comment: I did that, but still no luck. If I access http:// project:8081/, where project is a VH in c:\xampp\htdocs\project, I get the problem above. However, if I access http:// project:8081/something, css are loaded but still having problems with some links. Seems like css are not loaded on index (start page).

Another thing... this is a project imported from a online server. I've installed a fresh cakephp site locally, and it seems to work properly!